# Libcurl C++: Non-blocking way to send requests to a single URL

Tags: c++, asynchronous, curl, https, libcurl

**Goal:** To send requests to the same URL without having to wait for the request-sending function to finish executing.

Currently when I send a request to a URL, I have to wait around 10 ms for the server's response before sending another request using the same function. The aim is to detect changes on a webpage slightly faster than the program currently is doing, so for the WHILE loop to behave in a **non-blocking** manner.

**Question:** Using libcurl C++, if I have a WHILE loop that calls a function to send a request to a URL, how can I avoid waiting for the function to finish executing before sending another request **to the SAME URL**?

**Note:** I have been researching libcurl's `multi-interface` but I am struggling to determine if this interface is more suited to parallel requests to **multiple URLs** rather than sending requests to the **same URL** without having to wait for the function to finish executing each time. I have tried the following and looked at these resources:

- an attempt at multi-threading a C program using libcurl requests
- [How to do curl_multi_perform() asynchronously in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288513/how-to-do-curl-multi-perform-asynchronously-in-c)
- http://www.godpatterns.com/2011/09/asynchronous-non-blocking-curl-multi.html
- https://curl.se/libcurl/c/multi-single.html
- https://curl.se/libcurl/c/multi-poll.html

Here is my attempt at sending a request to one URL, but I have to wait for the `request()` function to finish and return a response code before sending the same request again.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {

        std::vector<char> *response = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<char> *>(userdata);
        response->insert(response->end(), ptr, ptr+nmemb);
        return nmemb;
}

long request(CURL *curl, const std::string &url) {

        std::vector<char> response;
        long response_code;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &response_code);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

        auto res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
     
        // ...
        // Print variable "response"
        // ...

        return response_code;
}

int main() {
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();

        while (true) {
                // blocking: request() must complete before executing again
                long response_code = request(curl, "https://example.com");
                // ...
                // Some condition breaks loop
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
        return 0;
}
```

I'm at a point where I have tried to understand the `multi-interface` documentation as best as possible, but still struggle to fully understand it / determine if it's actually suited to my particular problem. Apologies if this question appears to have not provided enough of my own research, but there are gaps in my libcurl knowledge I'm struggling to fill.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could suggest / explain ways in which I can modify my single libcurl example above to behave in a **non-blocking** manner.

---

**EDIT:**

From libcurl's **C implemented** example called "multi-poll", when I run the below program the URL's content is printed, but because it only prints once despite the `WHILE (1)` loop I'm confused as to whether or not it is sending repeated **non-blocking** requests to the URL (which is the aim), or just one request and is waiting on some other change/event?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* somewhat unix-specific */
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* curl stuff */
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
        CURL *http_handle;
        CURLM *multi_handle;
        int still_running = 1; /* keep number of running handles */

        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

        http_handle = curl_easy_init();

        curl_easy_setopt(http_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");

        multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

        curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, http_handle);

        while (1) {
                CURLMcode mc; /* curl_multi_poll() return code */
                int numfds;

                /* we start some action by calling perform right away */
                mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);

                if(still_running) {
                        /* wait for activity, timeout or "nothing" */
                        mc = curl_multi_poll(multi_handle, NULL, 0, 1000, &numfds);
                }

//              if(mc != CURLM_OK) {
//                      fprintf(stderr, "curl_multi_wait() failed, code %d.\n", mc);
//                      break;
//              }
        }

        curl_multi_remove_handle(multi_handle, http_handle);
        curl_easy_cleanup(http_handle);
        curl_multi_cleanup(multi_handle);
        curl_global_cleanup();

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe this reference will help https://curl.se/libcurl/c/multi-app.html
It performs 2 curls in parallel

Comment: I read through your reference https://curl.se/libcurl/c/multi-poll.html and it seems to fit what you are describing. In particular what issues do you have? Are you asking for an alternative to curls multi-interface?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ChristopherLeong . When running that particular example, the program prints out the URL contents once and then finishes. I was hoping to run the program continually with a WHILE loop and print the contents each time, but I'm unsure if this does the same thing? As an experiment, ideally it would be good if I could replace the WHILE loop with a FOR loop , run 10 iterations for my original program and 10 for the multi-poll and see if there is an execution time advantage. I will edit the question with the multi-poll attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move curl_multi_add_handle and curl_multi_remove_handle inside the
while loop. Below is the extract from curl documentation https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html

> When a single transfer is completed, the easy handle is still left added to the >multi stack. You need to first remove the easy handle with curl_multi_remove_handle >and then close it with curl_easy_cleanup, or possibly set new options to it and add >it again with curl_multi_add_handle to start another transfer.